# Embedding Multi-threaded Application inside Vert.x

Tags: multithreading, vert.x

We plan to use Vert.x framework for setting up our microservice, but at the same time we need to embed a third party application inside our microservice. This third-party application is multi-threaded, and thus I am not sure if this can be safely embedded inside our Vert.x based microservice. Can someone suggest reliable ways to proceed on this.
PS: I am very new to Vert.x so pardon me for my ignorance of it's internals, but I do understand Vert.x doesn't recommend multi-threading and goes with the Verticles based approach.

Comment: I think you can always call that "third party application" methods and/or functions from "worker" verticles and assume that it's a blocking call (unless you know it is not).

Comment: If you are planning for microservices then why don't you host the Multi-Threaded as one microservice and let all other vertx microservices consume it. Isn't that microservice?

Comment: The idea is to start with a single service (thus avoid any cost/management overhead initially) using a Micro-Service based framework like Vert.x , but we should be able to easily split it into multiple services going forward as our feature-set grows and user base increases.

Comment: I think using worker verticles making blocking calls should be a fair assumption, though initially I had some concern around thread management, but from a rough overview of Vert.x now it looks like it's more like a library and not a container, thus should not cause any issues with any multi-threaded application which can be assumed as a blocking call from Vert.x. Please correct me if I am wrong or might be missing something.